# How to run 'primusrun' command with Steam for Wndows games on Wine

Tags: nvidia, wine, games, nvidia-optimus, steam

I'm new on Ubuntu 14.04, and I was trying to find out how to run `primusrun` command (Bumblebee) on **Steam for Windows** games simulated with **Wine 1.6.2**. I have searched many forums and could not find the answer. My computer is a **L502x** with Optimus Nvidia Technology.

I Hope someone can help me, I will wait for the answers.
Thanks.

Comment: I thought it is look alike Wine command, not Bumblebee.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a Steam shortcut on your desktop. If so, you can right click on that shortcut, select Properties, and modify the command to include `primusrun`. You should insert it just before the `wine` command, with a space to either side of `primusrun`

[image: Configure Steam to use primusrun]